# Mercedes Benz Vito 116 cdi

Tags: catalytic-converter

Is it is safe to remove the "cat" in my vehicle? I have been losing power even after replacing the turbo.The cluster lights up the "diesel particle filter" sign. I have intermittent bursts of black and white smoke.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

Removing the catalytic converter most likely will not fix your problem.

The DPF is a separate part and it needs regular cleaning - usually it runs through a controlled cycle triggered by the control ecu.

If you do many short runs, lots of stop/start and ignore the cleaning cycles, then it gets to a point where the garage has to remove it to see if it can be cleaned or it needs replacing.

Comment: Not to mention you will likely fail any emissions test!